# Bootstrap navbar doesn't open - mobile view

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, sticky

I have a sticky nav with this code (Which is not mine)

```
// Create a clone of the menu, right next to original.
$('nav').addClass('original').clone().insertAfter('.navbar-default').addClass('cloned').css('position','fixed').css('top','0').css('margin-top','0').css('z-index','500').removeClass('original').hide();

scrollIntervalID = setInterval(stickIt, 10);


function stickIt() {

  var orgElementPos = $('.original').offset();
  orgElementTop = orgElementPos.top;               

  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (orgElementTop)) {
    // scrolled past the original position; now only show the cloned, sticky element.

    // Cloned element should always have same left position and width as original element.     
    orgElement = $('.original');
    coordsOrgElement = orgElement.offset();
    leftOrgElement = coordsOrgElement.left;  
    widthOrgElement = orgElement.css('width');
    $('.cloned').css('left',leftOrgElement+'px').css('top',0).css('width',widthOrgElement).show();
    $('.original').css('visibility','hidden');
  } else {
    // not scrolled past the menu; only show the original menu.
    $('.cloned').hide();
    $('.original').css('visibility','visible');
  }
}
```

It works great on desktop view but on mobile, when I try to open the menu the menu doesn't open and the page goes up. Here is an example: http://www.bootply.com/UYrOA0xDqa (Open the mobile view option)

My question is how can I fix it?

Comment: It does open? Just not with a fixed positioning.

Comment: this works fine on my case . there is no problem with mobile view. So I think you should recheck the page link .

Comment: Agreed. Seems to work fine. What browsers or conditions are you getting these results with?

Comment: @code.prio Here is a video, maybe now it's clearer, the browser is Google Chrome: http://screencast.com/t/OPdLiZqzp, is it happening only in my browser?

Comment: @Phil.Wheeler I added a video, can you review it pleas?

Comment: @Tal seem works fine with me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in / around the function called `stickIt` in you code.

I assume what you are doing is hiding the scrolling version of the menu and showing the sticky version of the menu when the top of the menu scrolls past the top edge of the page. You are doing this by setting `visibility: hidden`.

Unfortunately, because the visible open part of the menu is within the scrolling version of the menu, this also gets set to `visibility: hidden` when the sticky is activated causing the blank space.

You might want to trigger something to show the open part of the menu in the sticky too (it is open in the scrolling version of the menu) when the sticky is activated.